# Banach space of a unitization non-unital $C^\ast$-algebra and norms as well

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I've discussed a problem with good mathematicians here. We consider again a non-unital $C^\ast$-algebra.

Let's consider the following $C^\ast$-algebra. That is, the
$C^\ast$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}=\mathcal{A}\oplus \mathbb{C}$ as a vector space. We endow it with multiplication and involution,

$$(a,\lambda)\cdot (b,\mu):=(ab+\lambda b+\mu a,\lambda \mu)$$
and
$$(a,\lambda)^\ast:=(a^\ast,\bar{\lambda})$$

I already did some proofs including proof of homomorphism and norm etc. so we will take that for granted.

---

Now take $x\in\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ then we consider the linear map $\tilde{L}_x:\tilde{\mathcal{A}}\rightarrow \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ by $y\mapsto xy$ restricts to a map, $L_x:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ which is bounded with $\|L_x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_1$. This is already proven. Notice that we know the one-norm is given by $x=(a,\lambda)\in \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ by $\|x\|_1=\|a\|+|\lambda|$ and of course $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denote the operator norm.

Let's consider the following Banach space, call it $\mathscr{X}:=\mathcal{A}\oplus \mathbb{C}$ with the following norm.
$$\|(a,\lambda)\|_{\max}=\max\{\|a\|,|\lambda|\}.$$
Set $x=(a,\lambda)$ and let $x\in \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$, then I define the following: $p(x):\mathscr{X}\rightarrow \mathscr{X}$ by using a matrix given below, i.e.
$$p(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
L_x & 0 \\
0 & \lambda \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

**My questions:**

1. Can we verify that $p(x)\in\mathbb{B}(\mathscr{X})$ and further show $\|p(x)\|_\infty=\max\{\|L_x\|_\infty,|\lambda|\}$?
2. Is $p$ a unital, injective homomorphism of algebras?

Here $\mathbb{\mathscr{X}}$ is bounded operators on a Banach space $\mathscr{X}$. For my second question I know the idea of homomorphism but now *injective homomorphism*? Any suggestion would be helpful for me! If there are more conditions to show homomorphism, I would like to see how one of them can be done then I will do the other conditions.

---

Further let's define a new norm on $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ by setting $\|(a,\lambda)\|_\sim=\|p(a,\lambda)\|_\infty$.

**My third and last question.**

3. Is it possible to show the norm $\|\cdot \|_\infty$ restricts to the original $C^\ast$-norm on $\mathcal{A}\subset\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$?

---

I know that there is a lot of questions and I hope someone could help me to understand this way more better than I already do. I hope someone can give me an detailed answers/sketches so I can understand this and fill details. Thanks in advance. If I get a great answer I will mark it accepted.